# CFN stuck while ugrading ecs task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I want to trigger an ecs task upgrade via cloudformation. This works fine as long as the ELB health checks is ok after some time. 
In case of a failing healthcheck it never send this error back to CFN, but keeps restarting new task instances and wait again. 
Is there a way to limit the number of restart attempts?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a way to limit the number of restart attempts. However, you can set a timeout on cloudformation stack update.